# As soon as I hit render in cycles renderer, blender closes without a crash popup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

It doesn't matter what file, (I've opened up a new file and hit render and it still crashed,) but whenever I hit the 'render' button or use the rendered viewport mode blender automatically closes without an error popup from windows. This happens in both cpu and gpu modes, and exists in supported and experimental options for both modes. This doesn't happen when rendering with blender internal though. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling blender, to no effect. I appreciate any help I can get!

Error message from CMD: https://pastebin.com/BbZhw6L9

Edit: It also crashes when using the 'preview' window when adding textures, and gives me errors when I add nodes in the material editor.

My specs:
Radeon RX 480
Intel Core i5-6600
16 GB Ram
Windows 10

Comment: Try opening blender via the console and reproduce the issue. The console should remain open and register some errors.
An easy way to do this : go to your blender installation folder (by default it looks like this : `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender` ), then click on the path to edit it, and write "cmd" so that it opens the console in that folder. In the console, type "blender".
https://i.imgur.com/aGU72Qq.gif

Comment: If the output cmd report is quite long, share it to us via something like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Does this help? https://pastebin.com/BbZhw6L9

Comment: I would suggest resetting to factory defaults File->Load Factory Settings. Failing that download and run (not install) the standalone Blender package, choose .ZIP https://www.blender.org/download/ (select Other versions)

Comment: Sadly, load factory settings didn't work, and using a standalone package didn't fix the issue either. Thanks though!